# How to make javascript handle 'ESCAPE(\u001B)' character?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I want to make website that generate code for Windows 10 Command Prompt which supports 'ESCAPE'(\u001B) character to style string.
You can see examples on [HERE](https://gist.github.com/mlocati/fdabcaeb8071d5c75a2d51712db24011).

**NOTE: Since this site cannot show ``(\u001B) correctly, I will use `←` instead.**

The problem is, when I tried to make code that make code for Command Prompt like this:

```js
function cdGenerate() {
  var input = document.getElementById('ipText').value;

  console.log(`input: ${input}`);

  input = checkStyle(input);
  console.log(`checkStyle input : ${input}`);
  input = checkForeground(input);
  console.log(`checkForeground input : ${input}`);
  input = checkBackground(input);
  console.log(`checkBackground input : ${input}`);

  str = input;

  console.log(`str: ${str}`);

  document.getElementById('spResult').innerHTML = `<code>${str}</code>`;
  copy(str);
}
function checkStyle(ori) {
  var rtb = '←[';

  if (document.getElementById('g-style-reset').checked) { rtb += '0;' }
  if (document.getElementById('g-style-bold').checked) { rtb += '1;' }
  if (document.getElementById('g-style-underline').checked) { rtb += '4;' }
  if (document.getElementById('g-style-inverse').checked) { rtb += '7;' }

  rtb = rtb.slice(0, -1);
  rtb += 'm';

  var rtn = rtb.concat(ori);
  return rtn;
}
```

The result isn't not what I wanted.

I entered `TEST` in `ipText` HTML input element and execute `cdGenerate()`, what I should get is `←[7mTEST` like thing in `ipResult` HTML input element. But I can only get `TEST`, not `←[7mTEST`.

I've tested these codes with `←` instead of `\u001B` and nothing changed.

Furthermore, I need to copy those `←[7mTEST` to user's clipboard.

How can I make my javascript code to handle `←`(\u001B) correctly(as-is)?

Comment: What code exactly do you want to generate? Should the code contain the actual character, or should it have a readable escape sequence?

Comment: @Bergi At the end, user should get two outputs. [1]: user can see it. so showing the 'real' ESCAPE(\u001b) character would not be good. [2]: user can paste it. so it must contain 'real' ESCAPE(\u001b) character. Anyway, I've found there are lots of error in my script(do some work in string but not saving it) so I am working on it. I will add another comment here if I get another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found how to do it.

1. I need to show 'ESCAPE' character
   I decided to show `←` instead. And added comment to `<input>` 'DO NOT COPY THIS TEXT' like thing. All internal functions uses `←` instead of 'ESCAPE' because I only need it when copied to clipboard.
2. I need to copy 'ESCAPE' character
   After copy string into `<input>`, same variable is used when converting `←` to 'ESCAPE'. And I used hidden `<div>` to paste the string('ESCAPE' included) and copy it to clipboard. If `<input>` is used, 'ESCAPE' character is not copied properly, so I used `<div>`. Anyway, the `<div>`'s content is cleared after copying its content to clipboard.

```js
function copyToClipboard(string) {
  $id('hide').innerHTML = string;
  var temp = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.appendChild(temp);
  temp.setAttribute('value', string);
  temp.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(temp);
}
```

I hope my workaround help other people who suffers same problem.